# How to convert yamm3 into wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, megamenu

I am using bootstrap 3.2 in my wordpress project. I want to create a megamenu in bootstrap. I have found [YAMM 3](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/) has this functionality. But this is in HTML. Can any one tell me how can i integrate it in my wordpress project?

Comment: i assume you have already read the [docs](https://github.com/geedmo/yamm3)?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126015/creating-a-mega-menu -- this question has not been answered. It's a custom php script for the navwalker function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try use this nav walker?
https://github.com/macdonaldr93/yamm-nav-walker

so your code should look like this

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'              => 'primary',
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 4,
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav yamm',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'Yamm_Nav_Walker_menu_fallback',
        'walker'            => new Yamm_Nav_Walker())
    );
?>
```

Comment: Its working i have testing this with my new system. and this is great thank you man for your help.

Comment: Yeah, glad to hear that.. :)